# How can i remove the whitespace after fprintf C

Tags: c

Everytime i use this function to print in a file text. Even if i put \n after, it will place a space. I want to remove the space after it. How?

I want to print this: "List i :", not "List i : " but without blank space after ":".

```
for(i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
         fprintf(f, "%s %d\n %s\n", "List", i, ":");
    }
```

Comment: Only put spaces before the `%`s if you want spaces in the output at those positions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On my computer, the output of the code you have shown is

```
List 0$
 :$
List 1$
 :$
List 2$
 :$
List 3$
 :$
List 4$
 :$
```

I added dollar signs at the end of each line, so you can see that there are no trailing spaces.  On the other hand. the colons are being printed on their own lines, not after the numbers.  Is that maybe your actual problem and you didn't explain it quite right?

To get the output you said you wanted, either of these is supposed to work:

```
fprintf (f, "List %d:\n", i);
```

or

```
fprintf (f, "%s%d%s\n", "List", i, ":");
```